# Remove carriage return from string using vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

My code doesn't remove the carriage return from the string:

```
Imports System
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Public Module Module1

    Public Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World")
        Dim s As String = "your string" + Chr(10) & Chr(13) + "testing".Replace(vbCrLf, "")
        Console.WriteLine(s)
    End Sub
End Module
```

**dotnetfiddle:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/4FMxKD

I would like the string to look like `"your string testing"`

Comment: CR=Chr(13). LF=Chr(10). You have them the wrong way round ;)

Comment: there is no VBCrLf in "testing"; you are trying to replace it where it does not exist; and you will want to replace it with a space since there is not one between "string" and "testing"

Answer (score 7):

Note that vbCrLf is equivalent to Chr(13) & Chr(10).

Also, as Plutonix pointed out, you are applying `.Replace` to the string "testing". And you want to replace it with a space, according to your desired output.

So what you should have is

```
Dim s As String = ("your string" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "testing").Replace(vbCrLf, " ")
```

Finally, the above assumes that you meant that you want to replace the entire CRLF sequence rather than just the carriage return (Chr(13)).